# Grid selection of all rows

Tags: python, grid, wxpython

I have a problem with selecting all rows of a grid in wxPython.
The Code which does not working at the moment:

```
    def OnRangeClick(self, event):
    if event.Selecting():
        if event.GetTopLeftCoords() == (0,0) \
                and event.GetBottomRow() == self.myGrid.GetNumberRows() - 1 \
                and event.GetRightCol() == self.myGrid.GetNumberCols() - 1:
            for rows in range(self.myGrid.GetNumberRows()):
                self.myGrid.SelectRow(rows,True)
```

this part is Binded to a

```
EVT_GRID_RANGE_SELECT(self.myGrid,self.OnRangeClick)
```

and I don't want to bind it to a `EVT_GRID_LABEL_LEFT_CLICK`

what I want to do:
If the user is clicking to the upper left cell of the grid, all Rows should be selected(by `self.myGrid.SelectRow(rows,True)` and then I could handle this action. But after calling the `self.myGrid.SelectRow(rows,True)` nothing is in this array. All works, going throw the for-loop and the rows are also right.
I don't understand why there are NO rows selected...

Comment: I've solve this problem another way, but I'm also interested why this will not work!

Comment: i think EVT_GRID_RANGE_SELECT is fired when clicking on row not on cell. Would that explain why?

Comment: yeah I've found that too. Thanks a lot!